# Docker-compose failed running a jar that read configuration from a file

Tags: docker, jar, docker-compose

I want to run a jar on a docker container, it was working fine, but if I use a jar that need to read from a config file it fail.

The next is my docker-compose.yml:

```
jar:
  image: frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  volumes:
    - /tmp
    - "./farr-api-0.1.0.jar:/fagor/app.jar"
    - "./config/application.yml:/fagor/config/application.yml"
  command: sh -c 'touch /fagor/app.jar'
  environment:
    - JAVA_OPTS=""
  entrypoint: [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /fagor/app.jar" ]
```

Exceptions:

```
jar_1  | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
jar_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
jar_1  |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
jar_1  | Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
jar_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jar_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jar_1  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jar_1  |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
jar_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
jar_1  |    ... 1 more
jar_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private long es.ikerlan.farr_api.config.AppConfig.id; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'plants[0].plant.id' in string value "${plants[0].plant.id}"
```

Comment: Can you add the steps when you run the jar in a container, not from the docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I don't try it using docker run, I am running with docker-compose directly. But I have execute another jar using the same docker-compose but without que config files and it works fine

Comment: Do you mean ```farr-api-0.1.0.jar``` can not work but other jar can? The log said ```Could not resolve placeholder 'plants[0].plant.id' in string value "${plants[0].plant.id}"```, it's Java error, not Docker error.

Comment: To me it looks like you are trying to start the JAR on the volume and I'm not sure if this is what you want to do. I would recommend to create a dockerfile, copy your JAR and other necessary stuff there and then really start it in the container. So maybe it it looking for the file on the host...

Comment: But there the problem is that the farr-api-0.1.0.jar don't read from the config files. Maybe I configured wrong the volumes. I want to have for example fagor directory and inside it: config/application.yml farr-api-0.1.0.jar in the same directory. Is it possible? Am I doing wrong this? @Tuan

Comment: @hecko84 But I would like to execute the jar on docker-compose, or call a dockerfile from docker-compose. My problem is that I would like to automatice full deployment of an app. This app has some service that I run on docker-compose and after thats I run the jars.

Comment: You can mount the volume like above, @Asier. But I suggest you to test them with ```docker run``` first to make sure the ```farr-api-0.1.0.jar``` and the ```config/application.yml``` could work inside a container.

Comment: With docker-compose you can do your deployment, meaning you can build and start docker containers, link them together and by that bring up your whole application. If you package your JAR in a docker image you can bring it up with docker-compose or even build it. By what I saw above you have one JAR and one config file. So I would create a dockerfile copy both artifacts there and run it manually or with docker compose, but I don't see the need for the volumes (and I think this is one place that might messes it up)

Comment: Using volumes is imho not a good practice as it makes your container mutable. After all the idea is that you have an image pass it to someone else and it will behave the same there. As soon as you provide your app via a volume, it can be changed on the host and by that you receive a potentially completely new behavior

Comment: @hecko84 I want that the config file could change, because there are the IPs and some more things, so when I run the docker-compose on other server I would like to edit the config file with another IPs or configuration. If I use Dockerfile the image could have the same config file and I can't change it. Am I wrong? Thanks ;)

Comment: @Tuan how can I run it with docker run?, I don't know how to transfer the jar and the config file with docker run :S. Really thanks

Comment: Is it a spring boot application? Good practice for accomplishing that is to pass configuration via Environment settings that you can define via docker run or also in the docker-compose.

Comment: Okey I would try with environment settings:S, But one problem of this application is that it by default take the configuration from /config directory, but with environment variables it would work I dont know. If is not another solution to use the config I would use environment.  Thanks @hecko84

Comment: @hecko84 In the config file there is a lot of information, more than 50 parameters...  I would try a env-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple dockerfile that copies your app to an image, mounts a volume and copies the config to the volume.

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim

MAINTAINER Asier

VOLUME /config

COPY your_app.jar app.jar
COPY your_config.yml config/application.yml

RUN touch /app.jar

ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

compose file can be simple like

```
version: '2'
    services:
      farrapi_container:
        container_name: farrapicontainer
        build:
          context: ./
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
         - "3000:3000"
```

By that you should be able to change config via host. Be sure that app references the config file properly.
Anyways I would still try to have the configuration done via environment settings. It's pretty straight forward to override settings in you application.properties with ENV settings in spring boot.

Answer (score 2):

This's not an answer, just want to show how to test the `jar` with `docker run`. Now we are:

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 \
    -v ./farr-api-0.1.0.jar:/fagor/app.jar \
    -v ./config/application.yml:/fagor/config/application.yml \
    frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim \
    /bin/bash

# Now when you're inside the container

# Make sure you can run Java
java -version
# Make sure you had your files
ls -la  /fagor/app.jar
ls -ls /fagor/config/application.yml
# Run it
export JAVA_OPTS=""
java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /fagor/app.jar
```

Comment: Really thanks Tuan, at the moment I would use Dockerfile to create the image with the config, and then I would run it with docker-compose. But really really thanks for your help. I give you my vote.

Comment: Happy to help, @Asier.